# How far does the delocalisation (resonance) effects for substituents extend for a conjugated system?

Tags: aromatic-compounds, nmr-spectroscopy, resonance, nitro-compounds, electrophilic-substitution

Let's say we have a conjugated system like this one:

[image: 4-nitro-(E)-stilbene]

Now, the delocalisation of the benzene electrons with the nitrate system means that the ortho, and para positions on the immediate benzene ring would be more electron deficient than the meta position. This effect will be seen in <sup>1</sup>H NMR and <sup>13</sup>C NMR signals for the protons or carbons on the ortho/para/meta position. Also, the electrophilic substitution on those positions will be affected.

Now as I understand, the resonance effects of the $\ce{-NO2}$ group is due to the overlap of N 2p orbitals with the benzene ring p orbitals, which skews the sizes of molecular orbitals, and makes certain carbons more electron-deficient than others.

However, are resonance effects independent of distances over which they act? I am not sure if distance would have any role on the skewing of the molecular orbitals.

Does the distant benzene ring, and the double bond in between also show the resonance effects from the nitro group on the first ring? If so, is it as strong, or is it weaker? Can this be seen in NMR spectra? or the reactivity of the distant benzene ring?

Comment: The effect on the reactivity usually becomes clear if you take an electrophile and try to let it attack in different position.

Comment: Whatever rule, the fact that a system has a high degree of effective conjugation (delocalisation) does results in the substituent exerting an effect on the whole. Of course one practically sets limits, but having the substituent, and particularly one involved in the pi system by mesomery results in the double bond being affected. It has an enhanced single bond character. How easy is it seen by hydrogenation I don't know, nor I know on the change of the nmr. They might be little. But the UVVis spectrum will be there to show that the whole system has changed.

Comment: @Karl, Do you mean using QM calculations, or experimentally?

Comment: @Alchimista, Is there a ballpark figure for where we practically set that limit for the mesomeric effect? (number of bonds etc.)

Comment: Take the phenyl ring at the other end. Its reactivity might be very similar with or without the substituent at the other side. Note that practice is complicated and textbooks provide neat example. Here performing a reaction would already give a moderately complex mixtures of products. Likely their analysis requires a preliminary separation. At the end end of the process you might find substantially the same amount of each compounds. In textbook case you would be asked about the activating/orienting effect of a generic ethylene bridge, for instance. The effect you correctly thought of might be

Comment: ... more or less weaker. But there is one and it can be dramatic on the properties of the congiugsted skeleton, therefore I mentioned the UV Vis abs spectrum. Think or look at some common dyes and indicators to get even a more evident picture. Push pull system are extremes of the ideas above.

Comment: @Karl meant in principle. That is why I felt to comment.

Comment: Neither. I mean analogous to the basic textbook pen and paper experiments that shows you why some substituents direct into meta and others into ortho and para.

Comment: "is there a ballpark figure for where we practically set that limit for the mesomeric effect? (number of bonds etc.)". There might be one in and for specific treatments and properties. But I am not aware of. As far as extended linear conjugated systems are concerned, a theoretical treatment goes as far as infinite chain (!). In practical case torsion reduces the extent of delocalistion, so the effect does not reach the other side of the molecule if the latter is long and flexible enough.

Comment: ..... What I wanted to tell you that there are strong effect in a molecule such as that in your sketch. Not necessarily evident on the reactivity at the phenyl ring, yet more evident or even striking in El. absorption or in the CC str freq. of the methylene bridge.